# The correct expression of 'follow his way (or method)'

Tags: american-english, expressions, spoken-english, informal-language

I asked a question on a forum, and somebody (let's say his name is Bob) answered it (but not completely solve the problem). Based on this answer, I have the problem solved.

I want to write the answer myself, but first I need to acknowledge Bob's work. So I was wondering if I should see '**follow Bob's method, I get this problem solved**' or so something？

Thanks!

Comment: ***Following** Bob's method, I **[have] solved** this problem.* Also note that the "bracketed aside" in your question text should be *(but **did not** completely solve the problem)* - and that's certainly a context where it would be very natural to contract ***did not*** to ***didn't*** unless you particularly wanted to sound a bit more "formal". There are several alternatives to ***method*** in this context *(**technique, approach, procedure,...**)*, but imho ***way*** doesn't really work here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To follow x's method is good English.

However, in your context, I would advise using: to solve the problem. And not get this problem solved.

Your boss at work might say this: And I want you to get this problem solved. Right away.

But, **in writing and at a more formal register**. to solve the problem would be much better.